# Windows 8 metro call standardstyle from code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am trying to assign a style defined in StandardStyles.xaml through code behind.

I tried

```
var x = Resources["UnfavoriteAppBarButtonStyle"];
```

but I get **COMException** on that code.

**Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.**

If above code is wrong than how can I access styles from StandardStyles.xaml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it

the right way to do it is:

```
var style = Application.Current.Resources["FavoriteAppBarButtonStyle"] as Style
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add this way also

```
backButton.Style = (Style)this.Resources["NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle"];
```

here `(style)` declare it as style type